# How to get Keyboard inputs into a kernel?

Tags: c, x86, keyboard, kernel, osdev

I am writing my own kernel in c. Now I want to code a Console to interact with the Kernel. It should work like the normal Terminal on Linux. How can I get a input over the Keyboard ? Do I have to use Keyboard specific drivers ?

Comment: Minimal example with PS/2: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/5c672f73884a487414b3e21bd9e579c67cd77621/in_keyboard.S and BIOS: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/5c672f73884a487414b3e21bd9e579c67cd77621/bios_keyboard.S

Comment: The 8042 chip (and hardware that may emulate it) is well documented. The accepted answer has a link to 8042 information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard IRQ within an x86 kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618111/keyboard-irq-within-an-x86-kernel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a driver in your kernel for the keyboard. Assuming a standard PC, the 8042 keyboard controller is pretty well documented (see http://wiki.osdev.org/%228042%22_PS/2_Controller for example). You'll also need to write a driver for the display, and again assuming VGA it is pretty well documented (see http://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Hardware). Then you'll have to write all of the terminal stuff that sits in between to connect the two.