# Interrupt Handler Works Only Once

Tags: operating-system, interrupt

For an operating system project I am trying to implement interrupts in x86 system. I am preparing interrupt descriptor table and loading. For demonstration purposes, I am working on keyboard interrupts. Interrupt Handler for keyboard works however only once. What may be the problem and how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I am using the same code as in the link below. (Sample Code)

[Keyboard IRQ within an x86 kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618111/keyboard-irq-within-an-x86-kernel)

EDIT:
This topic can be closed, problem is now solved. I needed to read keycode port only not act according to status port.

Comment: Post your code.  Crystal balls do not make useful remote debuggers.

Comment: Do you have any piece of code that demonstrates us what you have tried so far. (Or else this question will be closed).

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, this:

```
 status = read_port(0x64);
 /* Lowest bit of status will be set if buffer is not empty */
 if (status & 0x01) {
```

should be ~ this :

```
 while ((status = read_port(0x64)) & 1) {
 /* Lowest bit of status will be set if buffer is not empty */
```

To clear the device interrupt.  The original PC/AT integrated devices are edge triggered only, so you have to ensure that the source of interrupt is cleared before exiting the interrupt handler.